# React-Redux issue. can't find variable mapDispatchToProps

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux

I m working on app from the past 20 days around and installed react-redux around a week back. Everything was working fine until today when I am unable to start my app. I m using expo and when I use expo start it shows `Unable to start your application. Please refer to https://expo.fyi/no-registered-application for more information.`

In the error log, it shows

`unable to find variable mapDispatchToProps`
I have to try 5 to 6 times for successfully building JavaScript bundle. I even tried with uninstalling and reinstalling react-redux packages and restarted my machine but this issue is still there.

Now I can start after trying several attempts but I am afraid this will cause problem in production and building APK package for it.

***Redux code***

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) =>{
  return {
    cartItems :state
  }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) =>{
  return {
    removeItem:(cart) =>dispatch({type:'REMOVE_FROM_CART',payload:cart}),
    addItemsToCart:(cart) =>dispatch({type:'ADD_TO_CART',payload:cart}),
    removePermanent:(cart) => dispatch({type:'REMOVE_PERMANENTLY',payload:cart})
  }
} 

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Cart)
```

Any help or guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: Please post the code where you're trying to use `mapDispatchToProps`.

Comment: I have edit the question. Please check

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, according to [react-redux 7.2 docs](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch), the correct ways to forward argument to your action creator are:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
   return {
      // explicitly forwarding arguments
      onClick: event => dispatch(trackClick(event)),

      // implicitly forwarding arguments
      onReceiveImpressions: (...impressions) => dispatch(trackImpressions(impressions))
   }
}
```

So, in your case, I think  you should write, using for example explicit forwarding:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) =>{
   return {
      removeItem: cart => dispatch({type:'REMOVE_FROM_CART',payload:cart}),
      addItemsToCart: cart => dispatch({type:'ADD_TO_CART',payload:cart}),
      removePermanent: cart => dispatch({type:'REMOVE_PERMANENTLY',payload:cart})
   }
 }
```

Comment: I did the changes but it is still logging the same error.

Comment: Ciao, I try to update my answer by putting examples comes from react-redux 7.2 docs. If problem persist, error could be somewhere else. Maybe you could update your question putting more code of your component (for example the part in which you call `dispatch`).

Comment: One more thing I want to add that I tried to start the project in web mode and it throws a different error that store is not defined however I have defined the store. This thing is driving me crazy. Don't know what the issue is. After 4 or 5 tries, it works perfectly, no issue no warning no error.

Comment: So now problem disappears? One question: are you working with Expo?

Comment: No, the issue is still there. Yeah project is managed by expo.

Comment: Ok, I have to reproduce error locally. I will post you a comment as soon I foud something (don't you have a github repo to share?)

Comment: I have repo but it is private. If you could provide me your email. I will add you to that repo.

Comment: find me on github, I'm `gioexp`.

Comment: Just send you req. Please check

Comment: Resolved it bro. Just uninstall and reinstalled the expo app on my phone.

Comment: Very well. I tried to go to Chart and I didn't get an error. I just seen some warnings. Anyway, I'm happy you solved that. Have a nice day :)

Comment: No problem, it was a pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

This is where the actions are defined

```
const initialState = {
    cart: [],
    total: 0,
}


const cartItems = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'ADD_TO_CART':
       {
           const updatedCart = [...state.cart];
           const item = updatedCart.find(x=>x.key===action.payload.key);
           if(item)
           {
            item.count++;
           }
           else{
             updatedCart.push(action.payload);
           }
            return {
                ...state,
                cart: updatedCart,
                total: state.total + 1,
               
            }
       }
        case 'REMOVE_FROM_CART' :
            {  
            let updatedCart = [...state.cart];
            const item = updatedCart.find(x=>x.key===action.payload.key);
            if (item.count === 1 )
            {
                updatedCart = state.cart.filter(i => i.key !== action.payload.key)
            } else if (item) {
               item.count--;
            }
            // AsyncStorage.setItem('cart',{...state, cart: updatedCart, total : state.total - 1 })
            return {...state, cart: updatedCart, total : state.total - 1 }
        }
        case 'REMOVE_PERMANENTLY' :
            {
            let updatedCart = [...state.cart];
            updatedCart = state.cart.filter(i => i.key !== action.payload.key)
            // AsyncStorage.setItem('cart',{...state, cart: updatedCart, total : state.total - 1})
            return {...state, cart: updatedCart, total : state.total - 1 }
        }
       
    }
    return state
}

export default cartItems
```

Apart from this, I just simply call these action bind with the buttons onPress function like this `onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate("CHECKOUT",{cart:this.props.cartItems.cart})}`

In another screen/page, I used a single dispatch action like this

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) =>{
  return {
    addItemsToCart:(total) =>{dispatch({type:'ADD_TO_CART',payload:total})}
  }
}
```

This is the whole code about mapDispatchToProps.